# Error: File not found /home/vcap/app/xs-app.json

Tags: s4sdk, sap-cloud-sdk

trying to install the approuter currently, following this tutorial:

https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/18/step-7-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-secure-your-application-on-sap-cloud-platform-cloudfoundry/

When pushing the approuter to CF, I get an error:

```
 2019-04-29T08:39:34.43+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR /home/vcap/app/approuter/lib/environment.js:19
   2019-04-29T08:39:34.43+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR       throw new Error('File not found ' + xsappFile);
   2019-04-29T08:39:34.43+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR       ^
   2019-04-29T08:39:34.43+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Error: File not found /home/vcap/app/xs-app.json
```

This is my manifest.yml:

```
---
applications:
- name: xyz
  command: 'node approuter/approuter.js'
  host: xyz-93deb1cd-7b72-4060-94e7-30baef85d259
  path: approuter
  memory: 128M
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack
  env:
    TENANT_HOST_PATTERN: 'xyz(.*).cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com'
    destinations: '[{"name":"service-destination", "url": "https://gfuowb4ett234agtuthorizations-srv.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com", "forwardAuthToken": true}]'
    SAP_JWT_TRUST_ACL: '[{"clientid" : "*", "identityzone" : "*"}]'

  services:
    - my-xsuaa
    - service-destination
```

This is my xs-app.json, which is located in my "approuter" folder.

```
{
  "routes": [{
    "source": "/",
    "target": "/",
    "destination": "service-destination"
  }]
}
```

[This is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIfzV.png)

When I move the xs-app.json in the root folder where it seems to be expected, I get the following error message:

```
xs-app.json/routes/0: Format validation failed (Route references unknown destination "service-destination")
```

Comment: We are trying to clarify the behavior internally at SAP with the relevant experts and let you know once we know more.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the approuter is looking into the bound destination service and not the destination environment variable.

I notice that there is a **destination service instance** with the name 'service-destination' however you have already defined a **destination** in the environment variable with the same name.

Either one should be present.

I would suggest either maintaining the destination in the environment variables and remove the entry from service section

```
---
applications:
- name: xyz
  command: 'node approuter/approuter.js'
  host: xyz-93deb1cd-7b72-4060-94e7-30baef85d259
  path: approuter
  memory: 128M
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack
  env:
    TENANT_HOST_PATTERN: 'xyz(.*).cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com'
    destinations: '[{"name":"service-destination", "url": "https://gfuowb4ett234agtuthorizations-srv.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com", "forwardAuthToken": true}]'
    SAP_JWT_TRUST_ACL: '[{"clientid" : "*", "identityzone" : "*"}]'

  # remove the service-destination from here and unbind any destination service if already bound
  services:
    - my-xsuaa
```

or dont maintain the destination environment variable - instead maintain it in the destination service instance GUI (from the cockpit)

```
---
applications:
- name: xyz
  command: 'node approuter/approuter.js'
  host: xyz-93deb1cd-7b72-4060-94e7-30baef85d259
  path: approuter
  memory: 128M
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack
  env:
    TENANT_HOST_PATTERN: 'xyz(.*).cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com'
    SAP_JWT_TRUST_ACL: '[{"clientid" : "*", "identityzone" : "*"}]'

  services:
    - my-xsuaa
    - service-destination
```

[image]

Note:

1. keeping the **destination name** and **destination instance name** same
   might lead to lots of confusion.
2. Manually unbind the service-destination / destination instance if
   you are following first approach. removing the entry from service
   section does not unbind it automatically.